Latency problem with GStreamer pipeline
I have 2 CM4 boards with 2gb(tx) and 1gb(rx) rams. I use stream transmit and receive using 2 raspberry connected with UART(921600 baud). On sender side i use this pipeline
gst-launch-1.0 -vvvv -e v4l2src device=/dev/video2 io-mode=4 ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! video/x-h264,format=NV12,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 leaky=2 ! v4l2h264dec ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls=\"encode,h264_profile=2,h264_level=12,video_bitrate=360000,video_gop_size=29\" output-io-mode=dmabuf-import ! video/x-h264,level="(string)4.1" ! filesink location=/dev/ttyUSB0 buffer-size=960 blocksize=9600 buffer-mode=0 o-sync=true qos=true

And receive with
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/dev/ttyUSB0 blocksize=960 ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! avdec_h264 skip-frame=1 lowres=2 max-threads=1 thread-type=slice ! v4l2convert ! xvimagesink async=true

I could get latency about 100ms with 640x480 resolution , but if I use 1280x720 it increases up to 300ms and with 1920x1080 about 1s . It clear that it is buffer problem , but i can't find solution to this . Any suggests?
